# Nice textbook illustration of microwave spectrum for a nearly free internal rotation?

Tags: spectroscopy

Is it possible to find a nice textbookish example of experimental data for an internal rotation of a molecule, in which the rotation is nearly free? For example, 1-butene is supposed to have a nearly free rotation about its middle bond.

It would be fun, for example, to be able to show a microwave spectrum for this molecule that demonstrates the evenly spaced photon energies of a rotor.

Comment: I did find some data on NIST. Perhaps you could find more there: https://webbook.nist.gov/cgi/cbook.cgi?ID=C106989&Mask=80. Look at "Data at other public NIST sites." I was personally disappointed by the apparent lack of a nice visual spec for it, but perhaps I'm looking in the wrong place.